# C# How to select ListBox item with a RightClick?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selection

I have tried a lot of methods for this and done hours of research, but it just never seems to work for me.

This is my current code, and I don't know why it shouldn't work.

```
    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show();
        }
    }
```

Also I don't care about the context menu that can be removed I am just looking for a way to make the right mouse button select the item I click on.

Any Ideas?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in the method do you hit it when you push the right mouse button down?  Or the left?

Comment: I don't seem to hit it at all

Comment: then you need to investigate why you are not hitting it at all.  Is the method bound to the event on the combo box? (usually this is added by the designer in the InitialiseComponent() function)

Comment: i don't know how i would bind it to the event

Answer (score 8):

You are close, you just forgot to select the item.  Fix:

```
    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
            var item = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (item >= 0) {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = item;
                contextMenuStrip1.Show(listBox1, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  private void lstFiles_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)   //(1)
        {
            int indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrag;
            indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrag = lstFiles.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y); //(2)
            if (indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrag != ListBox.NoMatches)
            {
                lstFiles.SelectedIndex = indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrag; //(3)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add some description of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Each control inherits ContextMenu property from Control class. Assign your context menu object to the ContextMenu property of your list box control and WinForms will handle it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button== MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            int nowIndex = e.Y / listBox1.ItemHeight;
            if (nowIndex < listBox1.Items.Count)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = e.Y / listBox1.ItemHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                //Out of rang
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know much in C#, but I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue. From Hans Passant's reply I tweaked it a little to get the below code. I also found that I didn't need to put `contextMenuStrip1.Show(listBox1, e.Location);` in there at all. It was automatically called for me.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with and compiling at .NET 4. I also verified that the below code works for BOTH MouseUp and MouseDown.)

```
    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var item = this.IndexFromPoint(args.Location);
            if (item >= 0 && this.SelectedIndices.Contains(item) == false)
            {
                this.SelectedItems.Clear();
                this.SelectedIndex = item;
            }
        }
    }
```