# How to get item index from ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently using a Listbox and contextMenuStrip, after item right clicked how can the item's index be retrieved from the Listbox ?

**My function:**

```
private void contextMenuStripOption1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    Point ptCursor = Cursor.Position;
    int itemIndex = listBoxFiles.IndexFromPoint(ptCursor);
}
```

**Delete function:**

```
private void contextMenuStripDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    listBoxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to select ListBox item with a RightClick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229034/c-sharp-how-to-select-listbox-item-with-a-rightclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not assign the ContextMenuStrip to the ListBox; instead open it programmatically after you have determined the selected index

```
int _selectedIndex;

private void listBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        _selectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (_selectedIndex == -1) {
            return;
        }
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(listBox1.PointToScreen(e.Location));
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Now you can access the index from the menu item clicks

```
private void contextMenuStripDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxFiles.Items.RemoveAt(_selectedIndex);
}
```

No need to recalculate the selected index and to test for -1. The context menu is not opened at all if the index is -1.

Comment: i didn't understand this: open it programatically after you have determined the selected index, how can i do it ?

Comment: OK so now i can reach to the item's index, and i have in my Listbox menu 2 option one of them is Delete (see my update), in the listBoxFiles_MouseUp function i can reach to the item index but how can i do it from the contextMenuStripDelete_Click function ?

Comment: My code sets the member variable `_selectedIndex`. This one can be accessed in the menu clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the container control: listBoxFiles.Items.IndexOf(listBoxFiles.SelectedItem)